# Receiving two http responses for one request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I have an express app on one port and a react app on another. My express app has cors enabled and authenticates a user through Passport. This works and when I hit the login route through my react app I'm taken to twitter, prompted and redirected to my react app. However upon returning to my react app I get a single 404 error from my express app. When I refresh the page I receive the correct 200 status and the user JSON object that's stored on a session in my express app.

This is where things get weird. If I refresh again, in my express app console I get a 200 (with the correct user) followed immediately by a 404 error (with no user info). On my react app console I see that I've only ever made one call to my function which sends a request to the express app.

Here is my express app code

```
var app = express()

app.use(require('morgan')('combined'))
app.use(require('cookie-parser')())
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(cors())

app.get('/getUser',
  function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
      req.session.user = req.user
      return res.status(200).send(req.user)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
)
```

And here is how I make the request in my react app. loginWithTwitter is dispatched from the redux store and called inside componentDidMount in my react component.

```
export function loginWithTwitter () {
  return function thunk (dispatch) {
    console.log('run once')
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/getUser',
      responseType: 'json',
      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
    })
      .then(res =>
        res.data
      )
      .then(user => {
        const action = twitterLogin(user)
        dispatch(action)
      })
      .catch(console.error())
  }
}
```

A couple of quirks that don't make sense:

- This entire thing works perfectly fine (no need to refresh and no 404 errors) if I use a proxy instead of enabling CORS. And it also works if I disable CORS checks in safari/chrome
- I still receive double http responses even if I use a proxy or disable CORS in browser, but the double calls both come back 200 with the right data.
- This leads me to believe it is an issue with how I call my function and perhaps in the middle of one of the calls CORS headers aren't set properly from the middleware or the server doesn't know how to handle the consecutive calls. However I'm clearly not calling the loginWithTwitter twice because I've logged inside of it to check the call count.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Here is what the double response looks like in my express console. Note how they're both within one second of the other.

```
::1 - - [22/Feb/2018:01:00:18 +0000] "GET /getUser HTTP/1.1" 200 9135 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38"
::1 - - [22/Feb/2018:01:00:19 +0000] "GET /getUser HTTP/1.1" 404 20 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38"
```

And here are the request headers for my request

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: is one request an `OPTIONS` request, then the next one is `GET` - that's called a CORS preflight - it's not two responses for one request, it's two responses for two different requests

Comment: @JaromandaX They are both GET requests. And there shouldn't be any preflight checks for a GET request. I've tried it with preflight-continue disabled in the CORS middleware as well and get similar issues. I will update the original post with my express console results.

Comment: `They are both GET requests` - odd, what browser? `there shouldn't be any preflight checks for a GET request` you don't know CORS :p GET/POST *may* need preflight, other methods, a preflight is mandated -  check your request headers ... do any request headers trigger preflight according to the CORS documentation?

Comment: so ... is CORS involved at all? what's showing in the browser developer tools network tab?

Comment: @JaromandaX So I was using safari. However I just tested in chrome and realized I'm only receiving one 404 response in chrome with no 200. I could double check to see if any of the CORS middleware default headers trigger preflight. Now I have to figure out why safari is causing multiple calls but chrome, postman, even hitting the route in safari directly instead of using my app, doesn't cause multiple responses. The browser network tab is showing generic 404 and not an Access Control issue which would be a CORS thing.

Comment: `CORS middleware default headers` - preflight is not triggered by the server, it's triggered by either the method not being GET/POST ... or, having headers that trigger it - as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests)

Comment: I see what you're saying. I tried removing the Accept header from my fetch request but I'm still getting two GET responses.

Comment: can you show exactly what request headers are being sent, full list

Comment: When I console.log the req it says `_header: null` and `_headers: []` along with `_headerSent: false`. So I believe I am not sending any headers.

Comment: not sure what you're looking at ... I was interested in the browser console to see what the browser is doing

Comment: Those are from the request that gets sent to my express app. So they should be identical to the headers that are set from my axios request (minus the Accept header which I've since removed).

Comment: ok ... so can you now look at what the browser is sending in request headers by looking at what the browser is sending in the request headers not by looking at what you think the server is receiving

Comment: @JaromandaX edited my OP with the req headers from chrome.

Comment: That Content- type triggers preflight

Comment: What version of node are you on?

Comment: I'm on 8.4.0. And that's so weird that I'm triggering preflight even though I never set Content-Type in my code. This very well could be the issue but I don't understand how it would cause a 404 and 200 response or why it would show as a GET request and then not show up in chrome at all.

Comment: Where in the component tree are you triggering this?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson I have an app.js file that renders two things: a navbar component as well as a component for the rest of the page. I'm triggering the function within the navbar component.

Comment: @JaromandaX and to anyone who reads this and has a similar issue:
You were right, it was due to the way headers were being set. It was triggering preflight BUT enabling preflight through my cors middleware didn't help at all. What I ended up doing, which is incredibly hacky and still doesn't explain the issue, was call next() if the OPTIONS method was used (which triggers when a preflight request is sent). This causes the next relevant method to be invoked, which in this case would be my getUser route.

Comment: that sounds wrong - though, the code you show doesn't show anything about how you were handling OPTIONS method originally

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the way headers were being set. It was triggering preflight BUT enabling preflight through my cors middleware didn't help at all. What I ended up doing, which is incredibly hacky and still doesn't explain the issue, was call next() if the OPTIONS method was used (which triggers when a preflight request is sent). This causes the next relevant method to be invoked, which in this case would be my getUser route.

```
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') { res.send(200) }

  next()
```

Comment: did you try `if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') { res.send(200); res.end(); return; }` - just a thought

Comment: That works similarly to calling next() at least in my app. Now the issue is that sometimes the OPTIONS response is never sent or the GET response is never sent after the OPTIONS response is sent. 

In my app I'm receiving the user but its finicky and sometimes doesn't work, sometimes does. I can see in my express console where the responses fail because it'll only have an OPTIONS response or only a GET. Is there a way to ensure they're both sent?

Comment: Although I'm also sometimes still getting two GET responses and an OPTIONS response. Which is troubling.